# AD domains & DNS domains

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, netbios

I've long been a fan of **site specific DNS domains** (e.g. <site>.company.com).  With AD, having a separate domain means an extra pair (for redundancy) of DCs which seems excessive (in cost and complexity) **in small environments**.

As a result, in my previous company we had a **single AD domain but two DNS domains**.  This worked out pretty well but it also meant including the sitename in the Windows servers names (e.g. <site>name) which gives a redundant FQDN: <site>name.<site>.company.com  *(The reason for this is that, obviously, you can only have a single AD computer called "name" within a domain.  [Yes, technically you can have one per OU but in practice the NetBIOS/pre2000 name prevents this from being practical.])*

The answer then seems to be to give up site awareness in the DNS domain which may not be such a big deal with Windows (given that AD has subnet based site-awareness) but still seems *wrong* to me.

**So, what do you do?**

Also, if you have multiple AD domains,

- where do you put your user accounts?
- where do you locate your company.com DCs?
- what else should I be thinking about?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by your question.  What do you want the end result to be, and for what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

We have a single AD domain which spans our two sites.  Machines have a two letter site code in the name to show which site they belong to.  Then use use sites and services to handle setting up the different sites via subnet.

Comment: That is exactly how we do it across 15+ sites worldwide.

Comment: Izzy- can you elaborate a bit?  How big is the company and how big are the sites themselves?

Comment: Company is approx 10,000 users, at approx 15 sites (always changing) across 4 continents.  Sites vary from 5 users, to 1000+ users.

Comment: How do you handle the moving of a complete team from a site the other? Do you rebuild every computer?

Comment: If a team were to move from one site to another, then the machines would all be renamed so that they reflect the name of the site they are in.  A rebuild probably wouldn't happen just a machine rename so that people wouldn't have to worry about loosing there data which is on local disk.

Answer (score 1):

My motto has always been ... don't put intelligence in machine names. People will pester you forever with their requirements; they will want site, serial#, vendor, business unit, laptop/desktop, userid, etc. Over the years, things change, and you are either renaming for weirdo reasons or falling out of sync.

We run a generic name with a number in it, and use another place to store metadata on the machine, with anything you want.